# Swift function call and protocol

Tags: swift

In swift is it possible to declare a method property not as a type but as a protocol?

like:

```
protocol myProtocol {
    var data1: String {get set}
    var node: Int {get set}
}

class myData: myProtocol {
    var data1: String = "Boo"
    var node: int = 10
}

class myClass {
    func myFunc(data: myProtocol) {
        data.data1 = "Hello"
    }
}
```

Basically I want to say to the method look I don't care about the type. As long as the object conforms to the protocol its ok

Comment: Yes; the above code has lots of problems, but passing a parameter using a protocol as the type is fine. Perhaps your confusion is about the fact that `data` is read-only in this case? Or is there some other question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is fine, but to modify `data` you will have to declare a class only protocol.

```
protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject {
    var data1: String {get set}
    var node: Int {get set}
}

class MyData: MyProtocol {
    var data1: String = "Boo"
    var node: Int = 10
}

class MyClass {
    func myFunc(data: MyProtocol) {
        data.data1 = "Hello"
    }
}
```

I've also fixed the capitalisation of your classes.

Comment: Or do `protocol MyProtocol: class` :)

Comment: @JayLee I believe `class` is being deprecated in favour of `AnyObject`. Although at the moment I think they work the same.

Comment: Wow.. noticed [0156](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md) nearly two years late!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `associatedtype`.

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
  associatedtype CustomData

  var data1: String { get set }
  var node: Int { get set }

  func myFunc(data: CustomData)
}

class MyData: MyProtocol {
  func myFunc(data: String) {
    print(data)
  }

  var data1: String = "Boo"
  var node: Int = 10
}
```

Also, you should use `PascalCase` for both protocols and classes, and `Int` is the integer type for swift.

EDIT: 
I misunderstood your question. You can also specify a function parameter by an abstract protocol, not just a class or a struct!

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
  var data1: String { get set }
  var node: Int { get set }
}

class MyData: MyProtocol {
  var data1: String = "Boo"
  var node: Int = 10
}

class MyClass {
  func myFunc(data: MyProtocol) {
    print(data.data1)
  }
}

let data = MyData()
let instance = MyClass()
instance.myFunc(data: data)  // Boo
```

Comment: Thats not what I'm after the function in MyData declares a function with a parameter and type. I'm after a way declaring the parameter as a Protocol NOT a type

Comment: Are you asking if `HERE` in `func myFunc(data: HERE)` can be a protocol? If so, it is possible. If this is not what you are asking, can you elaborate more?

Comment: where in the code I put up in the question have i declared a function in the protocol!!!

Comment: I added EDIT, is it what you wanted?

Comment: @hoboBob In your question, there isn't any function in the protocol. The protocol just requires two properties. What do you mean by "declared a function in the protocol?"

Comment: @Jay Lee exactly. I get an error when I declare the parameter as a Protocol in my code though. Cannot assign to property: "data" is a 'let' constant

Comment: @Jay Lee thanks I got there. I didn't know about having to declare a class only protocol